# how to get the array from the javascript function to the html form as input field value by body onload() function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having 6 bootstrap cards where the card details are id,content. Onclick of every card I am getting the ids of clicked card into the array from the local storage now I want to send that ids to the html form as value for input field 
My html code is:

```
<body onload = "sample(),issample()">
<div class="form-group" >
  <input type="text" name="goal" id="goal" value=" ">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password2">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
```

My JS code is :

```
var goal = []
function getGoal(id, content) {
  if (goal.length > 0) {
     var data = { id: id, content: $("#cont_" + id).text() }
     var x = JSON.stringify(data)
     var index = goal.indexOf(x)
     if (index == -1) {
       goal.push(x)
     }
     else {
      goal.splice(index, 1)
     }
  }
  else {
    var data = { id: id, content: $("#cont_" + id).text() }
    var x = JSON.stringify(data)
    goal.push(x)
  }
  localStorage.setItem("goal", JSON.stringify(goal))
  // To get all ids
  var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goal"))
  var goalIds = []
  if (storedNames)
   storedNames.forEach(element => {
   element = JSON.parse(element)
   goalIds.push(element.id)
  });
  console.log(goalIds)
}
 function issample(){
 $("#goal").val(goalIds);
 }
```

I am getting error as goalIds not defined but the goalIds array is getting the ids but that ids are not getting in the form as a value how can I access the goalids in the other function
My cards code is

```
<div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(1)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_1" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_1"><b>I am redecorating</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(2)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_2" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_2"><b>I am moving</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(3)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_3" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_3"><b>I need help with a layout</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(4)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_4" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_4"><b>I am looking for species</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(5)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_5" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_5"><b>I am moving in someone</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(6)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_6" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_6"><b>other</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My styles code is:

```
var styles = []
var styleIds = []
function getStyle(id) {
    if (styles.length > 0) {
        var data = { id: id, image: $("#img_"+id).attr('src'),content: $("#cont_" + id).text() }
        var x = JSON.stringify(data)
        var index = styles.indexOf(x)
        if (index == -1) {
            styles.push(x)
        }
        else {
            styles.splice(index, 1)
        }
    }
    else {
        var data = { id: id, image: $("#img_"+id).attr('src'),content: $("#cont_" + id).text() }
        var x = JSON.stringify(data)
        styles.push(x)
    }
    localStorage.setItem("styles", JSON.stringify(styles))
    styleIds = styles.map(element => JSON.parse(element).id);
    console.log(styleIds)
    assample();
}
function assample() {
    $("#style").val(styleIds);
    console.log(styleIds)
}
function initStyles() {
  var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("styles") || '[]');
  styleIds = storedNames.map(element => JSON.parse(element).id);
}
```

Comment: `goalIds` is a local variable in `getGoal()`, you can't access it in `issample()`. You need to make it a global variable.

Comment: Where is the `sample()` function. Is that supposed to be `getGoal()`?

Comment: @ Barmar it is another function coming from the another js file

Comment: @ Barmar if i kept that as a global variable the duplication of ids is coming

Comment: `getGoals` needs to set it to `[]` before pushing into it.

Comment: @ Barmar i didnt understand where I should set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `goalIds` a global variable so it can be used in both functions.

Use `storedNames.map()` when assigning it, so it will be reset each time.

`getGoal()` doesn't use the `content` parameter, you can just remove that.

You should call `issample()` at the end of `getGoal()` to update the input field.

```js
var goal = []
var goalIds = [];
function getGoal(id) {
  if (goal.length > 0) {
    var data = {
      id: id,
      content: $("#cont_" + id).text()
    }
    var x = JSON.stringify(data)
    var index = goal.indexOf(x)
    if (index == -1) {
      goal.push(x)
    } else {
      goal.splice(index, 1)
    }
  } else {
    var data = {
      id: id,
      content: $("#cont_" + id).text()
    }
    var x = JSON.stringify(data)
    goal.push(x)
  }
  localStorage.setItem("goal", JSON.stringify(goal))
  goalIds = goal.map(element => JSON.parse(element).id);
  console.log(goalIds)
  issample();
}

function issample() {
  $("#goal").val(goalIds);
}
```

To initialize `goalIds` when the page is loaded, add another function:

```
function initGoals() {
  var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goal") || '[]');
  goalIds = storedNames.map(element => JSON.parse(element).id);
}
```

And call `initGoals()` in your `onload`:

```
<body onload="sample(); initGoals(); issample();">
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204546/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-how-to-get-the-array-from-the-javascript-function).